# ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "xxx" in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Facing some trouble with the query below and looked for options to nullify the error but couldn't succeed. Maybe the joins are not proper, and the query may not be in it's best optimized state too. Will be glad if you could help with this:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
   hpd_help_desk.contact_company,
   hpd_help_desk.incident_number,
   MIN(remedy.chr_imp_impact_main.start_time),
   MAX(remedy.chr_imp_impact_main.end_time),
   hpd_help_desk.closed_date,
   MAX(remedy.chr_imp_impact_main.end_time),
   24,
   remedy.chr_imp_impact_main.condition,
   hpd_help_desk.condition,
   hpd_help_desk.severity,
   hpd_help_desk.department_of_authority,
   hpd_help_desk.self_inflicted,
   CASE
      WHEN hpd_help_desk.assigned_group LIKE '%NOC%'
      OR hpd_help_desk_assignment_log.assigned_group LIKE '%NOC%'
      OR hpd_help_desk.owner_group LIKE '%NOC%' THEN 1
      ELSE 0
   END
FROM remedy.hpd_help_desk
INNER JOIN remedy.hpd_help_desk_assignment_log
ON (
   hpd_help_desk.incident_number = hpd_help_desk_assignment_log.incident_number
)
LEFT OUTER JOIN remedy.chr_imp_impact_main
ON (
   hpd_help_desk.incident_number = chr_imp_impact_main.sourcerequestid
)
WHERE (
   CASE
      WHEN hpd_help_desk.assigned_group LIKE '%NOC%'
      OR hpd_help_desk_assignment_log.assigned_group LIKE '%NOC%'
      OR hpd_help_desk.owner_group LIKE '%NOC%' THEN 1
      ELSE 0
   END = 1
   AND CASE
      WHEN hpd_help_desk.self_inflicted IN ('0', '2')--ENUMID for Yes & Under Review are 0 & 2 resp
      AND hpd_help_desk.condition = '1' --ENUMID for Impairment = 1
      OR hpd_help_desk.condition = '0' THEN 1 --ENUMID for Outage = 0
      ELSE 0
   END = 1
)
GROUP BY 
   hpd_help_desk.contact_company,
   hpd_help_desk.condition,
   hpd_help_desk.self_inflicted,
   hpd_help_desk.incident_number,
   chr_imp_impact_main.condition,
   hpd_help_desk.closed_date,
   hpd_help_desk.severity,
   hpd_help_desk.department_of_authority,
   CASE
      WHEN hpd_help_desk.assigned_group LIKE '%NOC%'
      OR hdp_help_desk_assignment_log.assigned_group LIKE '%NOC%'
      OR hpd_help_desk.owner_group LIKE '%NOC%' THEN 1
      ELSE 0
   END'
```

I am getting an error :

`ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "hdp_help_desk_assignment_log"`

Working on Postgres as our database. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you have a typo, "hpd_" vs "hdp_"... in the the GROUP BY CASE.

Comment: My goodness, such foolishness at my end! Thank you so so much for the help :) No errors now, but any way out to optimize the query?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Postgresql to make any suggestions, but I would think aliasing the tables could make the query much more readable and less prone to such typos.

Comment: DISTINCT is superfluous because you are using GROUP BY (GROUP BY deduplicates the resulting data). Run your query prefixed by `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE) ...` and post the results into https://explain.depesz.com/ and share the link for review. You can also ask about the query plan in dba-stackexchange.com, and please provide your Postgresql version with the results.